# Detect keyboard with HostListener

Tags: angular

I create a few components in angular (4.0.0) to detect keyboard language (rus-eng) with decorator HostListener:

```
// detect keyboard lan
@HostListener("window:keypress", ["$event"])
public detectKeyboard(keyCode: number, mode: string): void {
    // if current lan is Rus
    if (mode === "Rus") {
        if (keyCode >= 128 && keyCode <= 255) {
            this.currentKeyboard = "Rus On";
        } else {
            this.currentKeyboard = "Eng On";
        }
    }
}
```

And this method is interfacing keyboard message

```
// interfacing keyboard message
public getKeyboard(): string {
    return this.currentKeyboard;
}
```

This is template:

```
<div *ngIf="getKeyboard()" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{currentKeyboard}}
</div>
```

And i add output to share in another component:

```
@Output("keyBoard") public keyBoard: EventEmitter<Object>;
```

In template of another component i call this:

```
<div (keypress.keyBoard)="detectKeyboard($event.keyCode, 'Rus')">
</div>
```

And problem with HostLitener decorator, i can't call my method detectKeyboard, and i don't why. Maybe problem with parameters of HostListener?

Comment: Hi,  I am also looking for same solution. Have you got solution?